Conversion of TradingView Pine Script Function to TradeStation EasyLanguage
I am attempting to convert the following Function that calculates some linear Regression values (seems to be nonstandard LR stuff). Everything is fairly straightforward except for one statement regarding the bar_index.
I have included the first part of the Pine Script Indicator and the Function that needs to be converted. What would I code in EasyLanguage to be equivalent to the statement?
` linear_regression = ((m * bar_index + c)*-1)
I am assuming that the EasyLanguage equivalent variable is CurrentBar, but that provides excessive values for the final calculation, which does not provide a similar value in Pine Script.
Here is what I am attempting to convert:
int length   = input.int(20, "Length")
float upper  = input.float(1.5,  "Upper Threshold", step = 0.1)
float lower  = input.float(-1.5, "Lower Threshold", step = 0.1)

bool candles = input.bool(false, "Plot Bar Color")

color col_up = #10cab8
color col_dn = color.blue

// Source
series float source = close[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1]

// Max and Min prices for Invalidation Levels (period 5 bars back)
var lowest              = array.new<float>(5)
var highest             = array.new<float>(5)
var series float points = na


//@function Calculation of slope and intercept
//@param length LookBack Period
//@returns  Linear Regression Oscillator
linear_regression_osc(int length)=>
    n      = length
    sum_x  = 0.0
    sum_y  = 0.0
    sum_xy = 0.0
    sum_x_squared = 0.0

    for i = 0 to n - 1
        sum_x         := sum_x + i
        sum_y         := sum_y + source[i]
        sum_xy        := sum_xy + i * source[i]
        sum_x_squared := sum_x_squared + i * i

        m = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n * sum_x_squared - sum_x * sum_x)
        c = (sum_y - m * sum_x) / n

        **linear_regression = ((m * bar_index + c)*-1)**

// Calculate linear regression Oscillator
linear_regression = linear_regression_osc(length)

// Normaliztion
linear_regression := (linear_regression - ta.sma(linear_regression, 100)) / ta.stdev(linear_regression, 100)


I have tried to substitute CurrentBar for bar_index, but that does not work.
Many thanks in advance for your help and assistance. Much appreciated!
